# Preventing Linux to use all storage space (root(

Tags: linux, filesystems, root

my Linux systems (Ubuntu 16.04) very often gets out of storage space (root 100% full). What happens is that lots of old kernel versions are created during time. Some part of storage is occupied by unused packages and some with huge system log files. While we know how to delete the files and solve the problem I wonder is there a way to prevent Linux from getting into that state at all. I understand that we have to do preventive maintenance but still, I am curious if we can set up Linux to prevent this.

thanks

Comment: Related: [How does apt decide how many old kernels to keep](https://askubuntu.com/questions/620266/how-does-apt-decide-how-many-old-kernels-to-keep)

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu will not overwrite nor autoremove old kernels when fetching new versions. Each version of linux-image is a different package, not just a new version, so it does not behave as a regular package update. The new kernels arrive, the old are not deleted.

What I do (having just a dozen of servers, not hundreds) from time to time, after successful reboot to a new kernel, I manually remove old packages. This is fine for me. If it was not, I would exclude linux-image* from any auto updates that might be running in the system.

Comment: At least Fedir keeps only the last 4 kernels or so, I'm sure Debian/Ubuntu can be somehow configured to do the same.